# AWS Pinpoint - not able to filter segment by locale

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, aws-pinpoint

I'm facing quite a big problem with *AWS Pinpoint*. Our application is an **iOS native app** and **we want to send marketing push notifications based on the user's locale**. Unfortunately, I cannot filter the segment by *Pinpoint's* default *endpoint* attribute `Locale`.

All of our *endpoints* are properly created and updated. What makes me curious about this issue is that the *Pinpoint* UI shows me all of the available values for the `Locale` attribute. But once I set any value, the console displays an error.

##### The following images show both the errors and filter applied:

*Pinpoint error message after submitting the segment:*
[image: Pinpoint error message after submitting the segment]

*Pinpoint error message after setting locale attribute value*
[image: Pinpoint error message after setting locale attribute value]

*Pinpoint segment filter*
[image: Pinpoint segment filter]

Any help or advice is appreciated!